# In VIM how to make NERDTree open at startup nicely when giving args

Tags: vim, args, nerdtree

Let me explain my question, what I want to do is:

1. From the command line calling `gvim` without arguments, want NERDTree open by default in my  `/home/user/Documents` folder.
2. From the command line calling `gvim .` want to open NERDTree with the directory set to the actual directory where the command was executed from. BUT I still want NERDTree on the left and a empty buffer in the right (not NERDTree being the only window just like normally happens).
3. From the command line calling `gvim /some/path/to/folder` want to open NERDTree with the directory set to the given directory. BUT I still want NERDTree on the left and a empty buffer in the right (not NERDTree being the only window just like normally happens).
4. When calling `gvim` with an argument:

   - If it is a file, don't open NERDTree just the file.
   - If it is a directory NERDTree should work as `#3`

To address `#1` I have:

```
function! StartUp()
    if 0 == argc()
        NERDTree ~/Documents
    endif
endfunction

autocmd VimEnter * call StartUp()
autocmd VimEnter * wincmd p
```

What I was thinking to address `#2` and `#3` was:

```
function! StartUp()
    if 0 == argc()
        NERDTree ~/Documents
    else
        if argv(0) == '.'
            NERDTree expand(getcwd())
        else
            NERDTree expand(argv(0))
        endif
    endif
endfunction

autocmd VimEnter * call StartUp()
autocmd VimEnter * wincmd p
```

But it doesn't work, it gives me errors and vim freezes some times. What I can do to achieve the desired effect?

Thanks for your help.

## Complete solution

Does not work exactly as I expected but it's very very close. So far so god.

```
function! StartUp()
    if 0 == argc()
        NERDTree ~/Documents
    else
        if argv(0) == '.'
            execute 'NERDTree' getcwd()
        else
            execute 'NERDTree' getcwd() . '/' . argv(0)
        endif
    endif
endfunction

autocmd VimEnter * call StartUp()
autocmd VimEnter * wincmd p
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't give you a complete solution, but here's a hint that should resolve the errors:

The `:NERDTree` command takes an (optional) directory; this doesn't resolve expressions. Vim's evaluation rules are different than most programming languages. You need to use `:execute` in order to evaluate a variable (or expression); otherwise, it's taken literally; i.e. Vim uses the variable name itself as the argument. So change this:

```
NERDTree expand(getcwd())
```

into:

```
execute 'NERDTree' getcwd()
```

I've also left out the `expand()`, as `getcwd()` already returns a full path.