# Automatically open two panes

Tags: vim, nerdtree

I open `nerdtree` by doing:

```
$ mvim .
```

If I then do:

```
:NERDTree
```

I get two vertical panes showing a tree view.  In the left pane, if I navigate to a file and hit `o`, the file opens in the right pane.  On the other hand, if I navigate to a file in the right pane and hit `o`, the file opens in the right pane.    That is the setup I want, but I don't want to have to type `:NERDTree` to get there.

I am trying to setup nerdtree so that when I do:

```
$ mvim .
```

two vertical panes open up automatically.  I found this vimscript:

```
"Nerdtree--open two windows on startup
autocmd vimenter * call s:CheckToSplitTwoTrees()
function! s:CheckToSplitTwoTrees()
    if argc() != 1 || !isdirectory(argv(0))
        return
    endif

    vsplit

    "there should really be a better way to do this... e.g. :NERDTreeSecondary
    call nerdtree#checkForBrowse(argv(0))
endfunction
```

which does what I want, however `o` in the left pane opens files in the *left pane*--not the right pane.  What controls what pane `o` opens a file in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you simply want - on startup - to execute `:NERDTree` on the first argument if it is a directory, your function is ok, but just execute the desired command.

```
"Nerdtree--open two windows on startup
autocmd vimenter * call s:CheckToSplitTwoTrees()
function! s:CheckToSplitTwoTrees()
    if argc() != 1 || !isdirectory(argv(0))
        return
    endif
    exe 'NERDTree '.argv(0)
endfunction
```

When NERDTree plugin is installed, opening vim with a directory automatically shows a NerdTree browser (primary, where `o` opens the file replacing the browser) instead of the regular netrw browser. So, executing `':NERDTree '.argv(0)` opens up the usual (secondary) NERDTree where `o` opens on the *right* pane.

Check also this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27498962/in-vim-how-to-make-nerdtree-open-at-startup-nicely-when-giving-args).